# Cannot Connect to Wired Connection (MacOS / Lubuntu dual boot on Mac Mini)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, lubuntu, ethernet

I have a Lubuntu installed on a Mac Mini with dual boot.

```
$ uname -a
Linux platolinux 4.15.0-47-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 10:44:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Wifi can connect without problems, but Ethernet connection does NOT work

When I boot, the ethernet interface seems to be down. When I start the computer and check hardware with lshw I get the ethernet interface as DISABLED

```
$ sudo lshw -c network -sanitize
[sudo] password for plato: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 03
       serial: [REMOVED]
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:a0600000-a0607fff memory:a0400000-a05fffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0f0
       version: 01
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=57766a-v1.15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:a0700000-a070ffff memory:a0710000-a071ffff
```

I bring it up with

```
sudo ip link set dev enp3s0f0 up
```

then I get this

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:7b:8a:b8:c8:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:85:90:f0:5d:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

checking network interfaces says that the ethernet interface () does not get a ipv4

```
$ ifconfig
enp3s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7a7b:8aff:feb8:c835  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 78:7b:8a:b8:c8:35  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 305  bytes 38637 (38.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27  bytes 4160 (4.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1920  bytes 195426 (195.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1920  bytes 195426 (195.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.44  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::1567:dcbd:6c9a:ea0c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8c:85:90:f0:5d:fe  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13406  bytes 8630835 (8.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 3603
        TX packets 13526  bytes 2034742 (2.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18
```

Any help will be appreciated, I have been three days reading and searching without success

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can get IPv4 if you restart NIC and turn off IPv6.

`sudo ifdown [interface name] && sudo ifup [interface neme]`

For your case, the `interface neme` is `enp3s0f0`.

Please add

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

to

`/etc/sysctl.conf`

and then type the following command and press Enter on a command line

`sudo sysctl -p`

Next, please create a new file `/etc/rc.local` and add these contents

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/rc.local

# Load kernel variables from /etc/sysctl.d
/etc/init.d/procps restart

exit 0
```

and give the permission to execute to the file

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Robot. I 'll give it try that later today but I am afraid it may not be sufficient becasue the ethernet interface is not enabled after start up. (see the reult of: **lshw -c network -sanitize**, where wireless is ENABLED while ethernet is DISABLED after booting and this happens everytime).

Comment: Then please try restart NIC first as I added:)

Comment: Please tell me if it does not help you.

Comment: Mr Robot. I did follow your recommendations and after reboot it worked fine. thank you so much. now the interface is enabled from start and a ipv4 is assigned. **THANKS**

Comment: I am glad to hear it:) Please click the check mark so that everyone can understand that this problem is solved and the solution is valid :)